# Petite-Vue on-click missing in compiled html, and "not defined" for reactive properties in app

Tags: javascript, vue.js, petite-vue

I am trying to create a "fake" multi-page website by toggling div visibility using v-if. However I am running into two issues:

First `<a href="#" v-on:click="toggleText">click to toggle</a>` is being compiled to   `<a href="#">click to toggle</a>`. Same when using div instead of a href, and then it can not be clicked.

Secondly, even if I switch the div to a button I keep getting an error "showText is not defined", but I define ShowText as a reactive property in the app object?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Petite-Vue Example</title>
  <style>
    .hidden-text {
      display: none;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app">
    <button class="clickable" @click="toggleText">Click me!</button>
    <div v-if="showText" class="hidden-text">Hidden text revealed!</div>
  </div>

  <script type="module">
    import { createApp } from 'https://unpkg.com/petite-vue@0.4.1/dist/petite-vue.es.js?module'
    const app = {
      showText: false,
      toggleText() {
        this.showText = !this.showText;
      }
    };

    createApp({
      data() {
        return app;
      },
      methods: {
        toggleText: app.toggleText
      }
    }).mount('#app');
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Any pointers would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Event handlers don't appear in rendered DOM HTML as there is nothing in the HTML spec that supports them, so that's expected. Vue specific syntax like that gets stripped away and turned into JavaScript when it's compiled for the browser.

Your issue is that you're using normal Vue Options API which petite-vue doesn't support. Read carefully through the [documentation](https://github.com/vuejs/petite-vue) and example code.  You'll see there is no `data()`, `methods`, etc. options.

Your app should be written as:

```js
createApp({
  showText: false,
  toggleText() {
    this.showText = !this.showText;
  }
}).mount('#app');
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3drpxf8s/)

Note I removed the `hidden-text` class on the div element because `display: none` would always hide the text regardless of the v-if result.

Comment: If `toggleText` doesn’t need to do anything more complicated than what’s in the example, OP can get rid of it entirely. `@click="showText = !showText"`